# Непонятная работа стиля radioButton в Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Работаю над проектом, в котором я использую Bootstrap. И тут для меня нужно было найти подходящий стиль для новой radioButton. 
Сначала начал использовать стиль по [ЭТОМУ](http://andwecode.com/custom-checkbox-radio-with-icon-fonts/) примеру. Все работало отлично но когда я изменяю размер окна, стиль radioButton меняется. Тот кружек, который в середине кнопки, отображается на по центру. 
Тогда я изменил стиль и использовал [ЭТОТ](http://www.cssscript.com/google-material-design-animated-radio-buttons-with-pure-css3/), но увидел снова этот непонятный глюк. 
После долгих поисков в CSS стиле и тестировании, я  увидел что на одцентровку кружка влияют отступы ДРУГИХ элементов. Например:
Вот скриншет сайта при размере 1865x760:

[image: Вот скришет сайта при размере 1865x760]

На нем видно что все работает отлично. Но когда уменьшу экран (чтобы протестировать на другом экране) то кружек смещается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда убираю margin-bottom: 20px верхнего элемента (В данном случае это текст State downloaded at...) то кружек стает на свое место.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Год еще раз изменю размеры, то уже на кружек начинает влиять класс .row из Bootstrap и кружек теперь расположен правее обычного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я убираю margin-right: -15px, margin-left: -15px то все стает на свои места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: 
1. Почему отступы других элементов влияют на стиль этого элемента?
2. Кто может помочь со стилями, чтобы у меня больше не было проблем с данной ошибкой.
3. Может есть уже проверенные вами стили, которые работают вне зависимости изменений размера экрана.

P.S: Что не так с теми стилями. Особенно с первым, почему он так реагирует?

Comment: Скинь на http://codepen.io

Comment: В вашем примере для выбранного чекбокса рисуются две иконки - одна для внешнего круга, а другая для внутреннего. Эти иконки могут очень странно себя вести в разных браузерах, при разном зуме, с разными размерами шрифтов, и расположить их идеально по центру очень сложно. Мы пришли к тому, что для выбранного состояния чекбокса использовали одну иконку вместо двух. Пример иконок - http://i.imgur.com/DNUq5V2.jpg

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ато я не понимал почему такая проблема есть. Уже запарился искать причину. Так Вы советуете просто сделать картинку и вставить? А можете подсказать пример CSS кода для такого дела? Может уже решение готовое есть и работающее.